# How to show check mark when cell is checked

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 table view cell in tableview. And I want to show checkmark on a cell when it is checked.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class UserRightRoleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var roleTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var managerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet var readerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet var memberTableViewCell: UITableViewCell!

    var checked = [false, false, false]
    var cells = [UITableViewCell]()
    var roleString = ["Manager, Member, Reader"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Role"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<User", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "backToVC")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cells = [managerTableViewCell, memberTableViewCell, readerTableViewCell]
    }

    func backToVC() {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func backToUserRightTableViewControllerAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            checked[0] == true ? (managerTableViewCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark) : (managerTableViewCell.accessoryType = .None)
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            checked[1] == true ? (memberTableViewCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark) : (memberTableViewCell.accessoryType = .None)
        } else {
            checked[2] == true ? (readerTableViewCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark) : (readerTableViewCell.accessoryType = .None)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        checked[indexPath.row] = true
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the cell's `accessoryType` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function, in addition to updating `checked`.

And your `willDisplayCell` function can be made much simpler:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType = checked[indexPath.row] ? .Checkmark : .None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @rmaddy, I've already solved the problem by:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = checked[indexPath.row] ? .Checkmark : .None
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        checked[0] = false
        checked[1] = false
        checked[2] = false
        checked[indexPath.row] = true
        roleTableView.reloadData()
    }
```